# Remove label after x seconds in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, timer, nstimer

In my simple game(ping pong), I want to show a SKLabelnode on the screen when a point is made. This label has to stay for 1 second and after that it has to dissappear.

How do I do this?

PS: I can not use the "sleep" function because I want the other code keep running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `SKSequence` to add and remove the label. A sequence does start the actions delayed after the one before has finished.

```
var timeToWait:NSTimeInterval = 2.0

//Wait a given amount of time. Here 2 seconds
var waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(timeToWait)

//Block to add your Label
var addLabelBlock = SKAction.runBlock({
    addChild(yourLabel)
})
//Action to remove your label from the parent.
var removeNodeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()

//Everything put in a sequence
var addAndRemoveSequence = SKAction.sequence([addLabelBlock, waitAction, removeNodeAction])

yourLabel.runAction(addAndRemoveSequence)
```